# How do I locate the offline file data in firefox

Tags: firefox, history, browser-cache

I used to locate the file data by going to cache directory, which I would locate by typing `about:cache`  in the Firefox address bar. I can still navigate to this page but the file structure inside his has changed. Earlier I would take, say for example a file of maximum size and rename it to .flv to get it working as a video file. Now I am unable to locate this video files. does anybody have any idea as to where would you find the cached files in Firefox(say you watched a video in YouTube) and now you want it to access offline.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this section of the developer documentation has the answer:

> **Storage location and clearing the offline cache**
>
> In Firefox, the offline cache data is stored separately from the Firefox profile—next to the regular disk cache:
>
> Windows Vista/7: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\.\OfflineCache
>
> Mac/Linux: /Users//Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/./OfflineCache

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Offline_resources_in_Firefox

Comment: though I am on xp, but it just given me one file index.sqllite

Comment: @refhat: Type "about:cache" into FF's address bar and it will show you where the various caches are located and there links that you can click on to view their contents. (I'm using XP, too, BTW).

Comment: @martineau: it worked before and I used the same trick. but with new updated ff, it doesnt show the same structure.

Comment: @refhat: I don't think it's a FF update that caused the location of downloaded things to change. More likely it's because the Flash Player plug-in has changed where it stores them.

Comment: @martineau: that makes sense, but I am confused about the various folder structures that ff creates like folder1, folder2, ...

Comment: @refhat: I'm at a disadvantage right now and not on my Mac, but if you can be more specific, I can take a look at it tomorrow morning my time (i.e. about 6-7 hours) and get back to you if there's anything I can clarify.

Comment: @refhat: If you want to save YouTube videos, check out [Adapter](http://www.macroplant.com/adapter/) which is a free audio and video converter for Windows and OS X that also happens to have a YouTube downloader built-in to it.